# Not able to convert the object of JSON to key/value pair in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

I need to convert my JSON data from like this :

```
 cacheMapDataDto = [{
    "cacheName": "cache_nchl_individual_type",
    "count": 2,
    "mapObj": {
      "NCHL_BI_BATCH_VERIFICATION": false,
      "NCHL_STL_BATCH_VERIFICATION": false
    },
    "nameOfCache": "NCHL Verification Status"
 }]
```

To this:

```
{"cacheName":"cache_member_dto_type",
"count":1,
"mapOfDto":[{"id":merCode,"value":"1"},{"id":merName,"value":"DE"},{"id":merId,"value":"10"}]
"nameOfCache":"Member DTO"
};
```

So ,I tried to convert the **mapOfDto** to key/value pair using following approach:

```
formatData(cacheMapDataDto:any){

  console.log("abc");

   console.log(cacheMapDataDto);


  this.result = Object.keys(cacheMapDataDto.mapOfDto).map(function(key) {
    return this.result[key] =cacheMapDataDto.mapOfDto[key], this.result;
  });

  console.log(this.result);

  this.cacheNewData={
  "cacheName":cacheMapDataDto.cacheName,
  "count":cacheMapDataDto.count,
  "mapOfDto":this.result,
  "nameOfCache": cacheMapDataDto.nameOfCache

  };

  console.log(this.cacheNewData);


  }
```

But,I got the error as:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
    at CacheMetaDataComponent.formatData
```

I am getting error at this line of code when I see where is the error coming from ts file:

```
 this.result = Object.keys(cacheMapDataDto.mapOfDto).map(function(key) {
    return this.result[key] =cacheMapDataDto.mapOfDto[key], this.result;
  });
```

Is there any good approach?

Comment: Hi Ashwin,
hope this help : your "Cannot convert undefined or null to object" error depends on how you're accessing your object.

Regarding your conversion just need to change it a bit to : 

`this.result = Object.keys(cacheMapDataDto).map(function(key) {
    return { "id": key, "value": cacheMapDataDto[key]};
});`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your modified question, try this:

```
this.cacheMapDataDto.forEach(cacheMapDataDto => {
      let result = Object.assign(cacheMapDataDto)
      result.mapObj = Object.keys(cacheMapDataDto.mapObj).map(key => ({ key, value: cacheMapDataDto.mapObj[key] }));
})
```

**[Working Stackbiltz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vzrkhp?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**